# Twilio TWIML nodejs gather sample code control flow

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-twiml

I was checking [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad-node-js) sample on twilio docs (v2.x but v3.x also is similar and my question won't be altered).

```
// This example uses JavaScript language features present in Node.js 6+

'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const twilio = require('twilio');
const urlencoded = require('body-parser').urlencoded;

let app = express();

// Parse incoming POST params with Express middleware
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Create a route that will handle Twilio webhook requests, sent as an 
// HTTP POST to /voice in our application
app.post('/voice', (request, response) => {
  // Use the Twilio Node.js SDK to build an XML response
  let twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();

  // Use the <Gather> verb to collect user input 
  twiml.gather({ numDigits: 1 }, (gatherNode) => {
    gatherNode.say('For sales, press 1. For support, press 2.');
  });

  // If the user doesn't enter input, loop
  twiml.redirect('/voice');

  // Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
});

// Create an HTTP server and listen for requests on port 3000
app.listen(3000);
```

So here is the fragment below blocking?

`twiml.gather({ numDigits: 1 }, (gatherNode) => {
    gatherNode.say('For sales, press 1. For support, press 2.');
  });`

If yes then assuming user enters something and we then move to 
`twiml.redirect('/voice');`

and other statements execute in sequence.

BUT if its non blocking, then `/voice` endpoint is called immediately and this continues in an infinite loop.

I was wondering how would the flow work.

**EDIT:**

The confusion seems to be caused by this comment
`// If the user doesn't enter input, loop`

If user enters something then also `twiml.redirect('/voice')` is being called. I am not sure how does that code even work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ricky from Twilio here.

This code doesn't create an infinite loop, but for a bit of a different reason than blocking vs non-blocking code. The way that you control a Twilio call flow is through [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml), which is XML containing a set of instructions of what to do with an incoming call. The node code in your `/voice` route isn't handling the control flow itself, but generating XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Gather numDigits="1">
    <Say>For sales, press 1. For support, press 2.</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Redirect>/voice</Redirect>
</Response>
```